# Configuring HTTPS proxy in Java

Tags: java, proxy

Is there any way to configure HTTPS proxy using java.net.Proxy class?
I want to communicate with an HTTP destination using HTTPS proxy from a Java client.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "HTTPS proxy"? Java uses unencrypted HTTP to connect to the proxy server, whether you use a custom `java.net.Proxy` class or the builtin one that is configured via system properties. For https destinations it uses the CONNECT method, so all communication between the client and the remote server is end-to-end TLS, it's just forwarded via the proxy server at the TCP level. But the initial connection to the proxy server is not HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimalistic example of how to set up proxying programmatically:

```
SocketAddress a = new InetSocketAddress("proxy.example.com", 8080);
Proxy p = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, a);
ProxySelector ps = new ProxySelector() {
    public List<Proxy> select(URI uri) { return Collections.singletonList(p); }
    public void connectFailed(URI uri, SocketAddress sa, IOException ioe) {}
};
ProxySelector.setDefault(ps);
```

Real code should of course do something sensible in `connectFailed`, and check the URI scheme in `select` if the application will also be using other schemes that are not supported by the proxy server. In the latter case it should return a Proxy instance that has the type `Proxy.Type.DIRECT`, which will cause the connection to bypass the proxy.

I have only used this with http and https URLs, so I don't know if it works with any other schemes. For https URLs the proxy server needs to support the CONNECT method.